# Xsl/Xml Issue structure generating html tags

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I have a problem generating html from an xml file via xslt.
I use a tei generated DTD with cbml customization for comic book.

This is my xml structure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE TEI SYSTEM "cbml.dtd">
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="sorgente.xsl"?>
<TEI xmlns="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0">
    <teiHeader>
        <fileDesc>
            <titleStmt>
                <title>Vi for Vendetta versione digitalizzata</title>
                    <respStmt>
                        <resp>codifica</resp>
                        <persName>Giulio Bambini</persName>
                    </respStmt>
                <respStmt>
                    <resp>traduzione</resp>
                    <persName>Stefano Negrini</persName>
                </respStmt>
                <respStmt>
                    <resp>lettering</resp>
                    <persName>Maurizio Pieri</persName>
                </respStmt>
            </titleStmt>    
            <publicationStmt> 
                <publisher>Università di Pisa</publisher>
                <pubPlace>Pisa, Italia</pubPlace>
                <date>2015</date>
                <availability>
                    <p>Licenza gratuita</p>
                </availability>
            </publicationStmt>
            <sourceDesc>
                <bibl>
                    <title>Vi for Vendetta</title>
                    <author>
                        <persName>Alan Oswald Moore</persName> e
                        <persName>David Lloyd</persName>
                    </author>
                    <publisher>DC Comics </publisher>
                    <pubPlace>Londra, Gran Bretagna</pubPlace>
                    <date>1982</date>
                </bibl>
            </sourceDesc>
        </fileDesc>
        <encodingDesc>
            <projectDesc>
            <p>
                La seguente codifica con l'ausilio di Image Markup Tool ci permette di identificare il testo annotato sulle
                immagini della Graphic Novel. All&apos; interno del nostro elaborato i dialoghi sono stati evidenziati in corsivo e 
                sono stati inoltre raggruppati i nomi dei personaggi, delle organizzazioni e dei luoghi evidenziati nel testo.
            </p>
            </projectDesc>
        </encodingDesc>   
    </teiHeader>
     <facsimile>
        <surface
            xml:id="img-1"
            ulx="0"
            uly="0"
            lrx="355"
            lry="678">
            <graphic url="tavole/1.jpg"/>
            <zone
                ulx="83"
                uly="223"
                lrx="272"
                lry="256"
                xml:id="line1"/>
            <zone
                ulx="92"
                uly="251"
                lrx="256"
                lry="282"
                xml:id="line2"/>
            <zone
                ulx="21"
                uly="281"
                lrx="330"
                lry="308"
                xml:id="line3"/>
            <zone
                ulx="36"
                uly="306"
                lrx="320"
                lry="332"
                xml:id="line4"/>
            <zone
                ulx="85"
                uly="535"
                lrx="249"
                lry="556"
                xml:id="line5"/>
            <zone
                ulx="97"
                uly="556"
                lrx="241"
                lry="576"
                xml:id="line6"/>
            <zone
                ulx="58"
                uly="577"
                lrx="281"
                lry="595"
                xml:id="line7"/>
            <zone
                ulx="68"
                uly="595"
                lrx="271"
                lry="613"
                xml:id="line8"/>
        </surface>
    </facsimile>
    <facsimile>
        <surface
            xml:id="img-2"
            ulx="0"
            uly="0"
            lrx="355"
            lry="678">
            <graphic url="tavole/2.jpg"/>
            <zone
                ulx="83"
                uly="223"
                lrx="272"
                lry="256"
                xml:id="line9"/>
            <zone
                ulx="92"
                uly="251"
                lrx="256"
                lry="282"
                xml:id="line10"/>
            <zone
                ulx="21"
                uly="281"
                lrx="330"
                lry="308"
                xml:id="line11"/>
            <zone
                ulx="36"
                uly="306"
                lrx="320"
                lry="332"
                xml:id="line12"/>
            <zone
                ulx="85"
                uly="535"
                lrx="249"
                lry="556"
                xml:id="line13"/>
            <zone
                ulx="97"
                uly="556"
                lrx="241"
                lry="576"
                xml:id="line14"/>
            <zone
                ulx="58"
                uly="577"
                lrx="281"
                lry="595"
                xml:id="line15"/>
            <zone
                ulx="68"
                uly="595"
                lrx="271"
                lry="613"
                xml:id="line16"/>
        </surface>
    </facsimile>

     <text>

        <body>

               <div type="panelGrp" facs="img-1" xml:id="myElement-1">
                <panel n="1" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">
                    <balloon facs="line1" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato" type="speech"><p>Buonasera Londra. Sono le nove, e questa è la<emph rendition="#b">voce del fato</emph> che trasmette sui 275 e 285 
                        in onde medie... è il 5 novembre 1997.</p>
                    </balloon>
                </panel>
                <panel n="2" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">
                    <balloon facs="#line2" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>Il tempo si manterrà bella fino alle 24:07, quando comincerà un <emph rendition="#b">acquazzone</emph> che durarà fino alle 01:30.</p>
                    </balloon>
                </panel>
                <panel n="3" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">
                    <balloon facs="#line3" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>Per tutta la notte la temperatura resterà tra i 13 e i 14 gradi centigradi.</p>
                    </balloon>
                </panel>
                <panel n="4" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">
                    <balloon facs="#line4" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>Si avverte la popolazione di Londra che da oggi le zone di Streatham e Brixton sono in <emph rendition="#b">quarantena</emph>.Si consiglia di evitare queste zone per motivi igienici e di sicurezza.</p>
                    </balloon>
                </panel>
                <panel n="5" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">
                    <balloon facs="#line5" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>I dati di produttività dell'hereforshire lasciano sperare che nel febbraio del 1998 si possa porre fine al<emph rendition="#b">razionamento</emph> della carne.</p>
                    </balloon>
                </panel>    
                <panel n="6" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">
                    <balloon facs="#line6" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>Analoghe speranze anche per le <emph rendition="#b">uova</emph> e le <emph rendition="#b">patate</emph> grazie al'aumento della produzione.</p>
                    </balloon>
                </panel>    
                <panel n="7" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">    
                    <balloon facs="#line7" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>Di primo mattino la polizia ha fatto irruzione in diciassette case della zona di Birmingham sgominando una pericolosa <emph rendition="#b">rete terroristica</emph>.</p>
                    </balloon>
                    <balloon facs="#line8" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>Venti persone, tra cui otto donne, sono attualmente detenute in attesa di giudizio.</p>
                    </balloon>          
                 </panel>
                <fw type="pageNum" place="lower-left">1</fw>
            </div>


            <div type="panelGrp" facs="img-2" xml:id="myElement-1">
                <panel n="1" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">
                    <balloon facs="line9" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato" type="speech"><p>Buonasera Londra. Sono le nove, e questa è la<emph rendition="#b">voce del fato</emph> che trasmette sui 275 e 285 
                        in onde medie... è il 5 novembre 1997.</p>
                    </balloon>
                </panel>
                <panel n="2" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">
                    <balloon facs="#line10" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>Il tempo si manterrà bella fino alle 24:07, quando comincerà un <emph rendition="#b">acquazzone</emph> che durarà fino alle 01:30.</p>
                    </balloon>
                </panel>
                <panel n="3" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">
                    <balloon facs="#line11" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>Per tutta la notte la temperatura resterà tra i 13 e i 14 gradi centigradi.</p>
                    </balloon>
                </panel>
                <panel n="4" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">
                    <balloon facs="#line12" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>Si avverte la popolazione di Londra che da oggi le zone di Streatham e Brixton sono in <emph rendition="#b">quarantena</emph>.Si consiglia di evitare queste zone per motivi igienici e di sicurezza.</p>
                    </balloon>
                </panel>
                <panel n="5" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">
                    <balloon facs="#line13" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>I dati di produttività dell'hereforshire lasciano sperare che nel febbraio del 1998 si possa porre fine al<emph rendition="#b">razionamento</emph> della carne.</p>
                    </balloon>
                </panel>    
                <panel n="6" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">
                    <balloon facs="#line14" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>Analoghe speranze anche per le <emph rendition="#b">uova</emph> e le <emph rendition="#b">patate</emph> grazie al'aumento della produzione.</p>
                    </balloon>
                </panel>    
                <panel n="7" characters="#EmittenteRadioDelFato">    
                    <balloon facs="#line15" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>Di primo mattino la polizia ha fatto irruzione in diciassette case della zona di Birmingham sgominando una pericolosa <emph rendition="#b">rete terroristica</emph>.</p>
                    </balloon>
                    <balloon facs="#line16" type="speech" who="#EmittenteRadioDelFato"><p>Venti persone, tra cui otto donne, sono attualmente detenute in attesa di giudizio.</p>
                    </balloon>          
                 </panel>
                <fw type="pageNum" place="lower-left">1</fw>
            </div>



        </body>
    </text>
</TEI>
```

And this is my xsl file for generate html:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:cbml="http://www.cbml.org/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="no"/>   
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html></xsl:text>
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:title"/>  
                </title>
                <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
                <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stile.css" />
            </head>

            <body>
                <div>
                    <xsl:attribute name="class">inner-container</xsl:attribute>
                    <div>
                        <xsl:attribute name="id">corpo</xsl:attribute> 
                <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>

                    </div></div>  
            </body>
        </html>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tei:teiHeader">

        <div>
            <xsl:attribute name="id">header</xsl:attribute>
            <h1>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">titolo</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:title"/>
            </h1>
            <h3>
                <xsl:attribute name="id">resp-name</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:respStmt/tei:resp"/>
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:respStmt/tei:name"/>
            </h3>
        </div>
        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">contenitore-tei-header</xsl:attribute>    
        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">informazioni-codifica</xsl:attribute>    
            <h3 class="titolo-liste">Informazioni sulla codifica</h3>
            <h5>
                Titolo: 
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:title"/>
            </h5>
            <h5>
                Codifica curata da: 
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:respStmt/tei:persName"/>
            </h5>
            <h5>
                Publisher: 
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:publicationStmt/tei:publisher"/>
            </h5>
            <h5>
                Città:
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:publicationStmt/tei:pubPlace"/>
            </h5> 
            <h5>
                Data: 
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:publicationStmt/tei:date"/>
            </h5>
       </xsl:element>    
       <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">informazioni-fumetto</xsl:attribute>      
            <h3 class="titolo-liste">Informazioni sul fumetto</h3>
            <h5>
                Titolo originale: 
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:bibl/tei:title"/>
            </h5>
            <h5>
                Autori: 
                <a href="item.php?id={ItemId}">
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:bibl/tei:author/tei:persName"/>
                </a>    
            </h5>   
            <h5>
                Casa editrice: 
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:bibl/tei:publisher"/>
            </h5>
            <h5>
                Città:
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:bibl/tei:pubPlace"/>
            </h5> 
            <h5>
                Data pubblicazione: 
                <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:bibl/tei:date"/>
            </h5>
       </xsl:element>     
        <xsl:element name="div">
               <xsl:attribute name="id">introduzione</xsl:attribute>    
               <h3 class="titolo-liste">Introduzione</h3>  
            <xsl:value-of select="tei:encodingDesc/tei:projectDesc"/>
        </xsl:element> 
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="tei:facsimile/tei:surface">
        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">contenitore-immagine</xsl:attribute>    
            <xsl:element name="img">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">dimensioni</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:attribute name="src">
                    <xsl:value-of select="tei:graphic/@url" />
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="tei:text">

        <xsl:apply-templates></xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:template>




    <xsl:template match="tei:body/tei:div[@type='panelGrp']">
        <xsl:element name="div">
            <xsl:attribute name="id">contenitore-testo-annotato</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:element name="ul">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">ul-testo-annotato</xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:for-each select="cbml:panel">
                    <xsl:element name="li">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">li-testo-annotato</xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:element name="p">
                        <xsl:attribute name="class">p-testo-annotato</xsl:attribute>
                            <xsl:value-of select="cbml:balloon"/>
                    </xsl:element>
                    </xsl:element>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
    </xsl:template>



</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is the generated html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:cbml="http://www.cbml.org/ns/1.0"><head><title></title><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stile.css" /></head><body><div class="inner-container"><div id="corpo">
    <div id="header"><h1 id="titolo">Vi for Vendetta versione digitalizzata</h1><h3 id="resp-name">codifica</h3></div><div id="contenitore-tei-header"><div id="informazioni-codifica"><h3 class="titolo-liste">Informazioni sulla codifica</h3><h5>
                    Titolo: 
                    Vi for Vendetta versione digitalizzata</h5><h5>
                    Codifica curata da: 
                    Giulio Bambini</h5><h5>
                    Publisher: 
                    Università di Pisa</h5><h5>
                    Città:
                    Pisa, Italia</h5><h5>
                    Data: 
                    2015</h5></div><div id="informazioni-fumetto"><h3 class="titolo-liste">Informazioni sul fumetto</h3><h5>
                    Titolo originale: 
                    Vi for Vendetta</h5><h5>
                    Autori: 
                    <a href="item.php?id=">Alan Oswald Moore</a></h5><h5>
                    Casa editrice: 
                    DC Comics </h5><h5>
                    Città:
                    Londra, Gran Bretagna</h5><h5>
                    Data pubblicazione: 
                    1982</h5></div><div id="introduzione"><h3 class="titolo-liste">Introduzione</h3>

                La seguente codifica con l'ausilio di Image Markup Tool ci permette di identificare il testo annotato sulle
                immagini della Graphic Novel. All' interno del nostro elaborato i dialoghi sono stati evidenziati in corsivo e 
                sono stati inoltre raggruppati i nomi dei personaggi, delle organizzazioni e dei luoghi evidenziati nel testo.

            </div></div>

        <div id="contenitore-immagine"><img class="dimensioni" src="tavole/1.jpg" /></div>


        <div id="contenitore-immagine"><img class="dimensioni" src="tavole/2.jpg" /></div>






               <div id="contenitore-testo-annotato"><ul class="ul-testo-annotato"></ul></div>


            <div id="contenitore-testo-annotato"><ul class="ul-testo-annotato"></ul></div>





</div></div></body></html>
```

My problem is that i want generate this html structure with altenated html tags(something like that..):

```
<div id="contenitore-immagine">
<div id="contenitore-testo-annotato">
<div id="contenitore-immagine">
<div id="contenitore-testo-annotato">
```

But with my current xsl it comes with this wrong structure(it matches all elements together without an alternation):

```
<div id="contenitore-immagine">
<div id="contenitore-immagine">
<div id="contenitore-testo-annotato">
<div id="contenitore-testo-annotato">
```

How can i do for generate alternated html tags?
How can i do for select text segments connected to the relative image?

Comment: When I run that XSLT on your example input, the result has 1 `contenitore-immagine` and 1 `contenitore-testo-annotato`, so it does not exhibit the problem you are describing. Could you please show us an input that demonstrates the issue and get rid of the extra stuff that is unrelated to the problem? For your reference: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Now in my xml file i have only just 1 <facsimile> and 1 <div type="panelGrp"> My problem is caused when i decide to add more of these xml tags. You can see just adding more.

Comment: Can you show us what that XML would look like? I don't know how your XML structure works, so I can't just arbitrarily add more.

Comment: I have edited just now my question. I have modified the xml with the exactly example, and i have added also the generated html.

Comment: Ok, thank you. Is it safe to assume that there will always be an equal number of `contenitore-immagine`s and `contenitore-testo-annotato`s, or can there be an unequal number of them sometimes?

Comment: Yes, always an equal number because #contenitore-immagine contains the image and #contenitore-testo-annotato contains the text encoded about that image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is how I would solve this:

Define an empty template for `tei:text`, so that the processing does not automatically flow into it:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:text" />
```

Create a variable with all of the panels in the source document, so that you can concisely and efficiently access them:

```
<xsl:variable name="pannelli" select="/*/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div[@type='panelGrp']" />
```

When processing a facsimile surface, determine the ordinal number of that surface within the document, and use that to apply templates to the associated panel:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:facsimile/tei:surface">
  <xsl:variable name="pos">
    <xsl:number count="tei:facsimile/tei:surface" level="any"/>
  </xsl:variable>

  <div id="contenitore-immagine">
    <img class="dimensioni" src="{tei:graphic/@url}"/>
  </div>

  <xsl:apply-templates select="$pannelli[number($pos)]" />
</xsl:template>
```

(not related to original question) Make some improvements and corrections to the panelGrp template:

```
<xsl:template match="tei:body/tei:div[@type='panelGrp']">
  <div id="contenitore-testo-annotato">
    <ul class="ul-testo-annotato">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:panel" />
    </ul>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="tei:div[@type='panelGrp']/tei:panel">
  <li class="li-testo-annotato">
    <p class="p-testo-annotato">
      <xsl:value-of select="tei:balloon"/>
    </p>
  </li>
</xsl:template>
```

---

Full solution:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
    xmlns:tei="http://www.tei-c.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:cbml="http://www.cbml.org/ns/1.0"
    exclude-result-prefixes="tei cbml">
  <xsl:output method="html" version="4.0" indent="no"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping='yes'>&lt;!DOCTYPE html></xsl:text>
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>
          <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:title"/>
        </title>
        <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stile.css" />
      </head>

      <body>
        <div class="inner-container">
          <div id="corpo">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </body>
    </html>

  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tei:teiHeader">

    <div id="header">
      <h1 id="titolo">
        <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:title"/>
      </h1>
      <h3 id="resp-name">
        <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:respStmt/tei:resp"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:respStmt/tei:name"/>
      </h3>
    </div>
    <div id="contenitore-tei-header">
      <div id="informazioni-codifica">
        <h3 class="titolo-liste">Informazioni sulla codifica</h3>
        <h5>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('Titolo: ', tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:title)"/>
        </h5>
        <h5>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('Codifica curata da: ', tei:fileDesc/tei:titleStmt/tei:respStmt/tei:persName)"/>
        </h5>
        <h5>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('Publisher:', tei:fileDesc/tei:publicationStmt/tei:publisher)"/>
        </h5>
        <h5>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('Città:', tei:fileDesc/tei:publicationStmt/tei:pubPlace)"/>
        </h5>
        <h5>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('Data: ', tei:fileDesc/tei:publicationStmt/tei:date)"/>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="informazioni-fumetto">
        <h3 class="titolo-liste">Informazioni sul fumetto</h3>
        <h5>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('Titolo originale: ', tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:bibl/tei:title)"/>
        </h5>
        <h5>
          <xsl:text>Autori: </xsl:text>
          <a href="item.php?id={ItemId}">
            <xsl:value-of select="tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:bibl/tei:author/tei:persName"/>
          </a>
        </h5>
        <h5>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('Casa editrice: ', tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:bibl/tei:publisher)"/>
        </h5>
        <h5>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('Città: ', tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:bibl/tei:pubPlace)"/>
        </h5>
        <h5>
          <xsl:value-of select="concat('Data pubblicazione: ', tei:fileDesc/tei:sourceDesc/tei:bibl/tei:date)"/>
        </h5>
      </div>
      <div id="introduzione">
        <h3 class="titolo-liste">Introduzione</h3>
        <xsl:value-of select="tei:encodingDesc/tei:projectDesc"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tei:text" />

  <xsl:variable name="pannelli" select="/*/tei:text/tei:body/tei:div[@type='panelGrp']" />

  <xsl:template match="tei:facsimile/tei:surface">
    <xsl:variable name="pos">
      <xsl:number count="tei:facsimile/tei:surface" level="any"/>
    </xsl:variable>

    <div id="contenitore-immagine">
      <img class="dimensioni" src="{tei:graphic/@url}"/>
    </div>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$pannelli[number($pos)]" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tei:body/tei:div[@type='panelGrp']">
    <div id="contenitore-testo-annotato">
      <ul class="ul-testo-annotato">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:panel" />
      </ul>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="tei:div[@type='panelGrp']/tei:panel">
    <li class="li-testo-annotato">
      <p class="p-testo-annotato">
        <xsl:value-of select="tei:balloon"/>
      </p>
    </li>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I have tested your solution and with some tips it works. I have change this:   <xsl:apply-templates select="tei:panel" /> with this <xsl:apply-templates select="cbml:panel" />

Comment: @GiulioBambini Great. In the XML you provided, `panel` and `balloon` are in the `tei:` namespace, so that's why I changed them. Perhaps that was different from your actual XML.

Comment: At present with this xml/xsl structure how can i do something like in this example for connect image zone to noted text? http://users.ox.ac.uk/~rahtz/test4.html