# How to create with xml/xsl/javascript a web view between noted texts and images

Tags: javascript, html, xml, xslt, onmouseover

I want to create something similar at this example:
http://users.ox.ac.uk/~rahtz/test4.html

It's something where your annotations appear as mouse-over outlines with boxes displaying the annotations position on relative images. I think it could be done also with some javascript tips, as the example above. Maybe generating from xsl for each tag p a new tag span with attributes reference onMouseOver connected with javascript function.

In my xml structure i have used the facsimile elements for display images, and also the zone elements with coordinates and xml:id for define the portion of text. These zone elements represents an area inside surface element (maybe connected to some texts).

You can see my xml/xsl structure here: [Xsl/Xml Issue structure generating html tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29171792/xsl-xml-issue-structure-generating-html-tags)

Approximately i think i have to generate something like this:

```
<div id="contenitore-immagine">
        <img class="dimensioni" src="tavole/1.jpg">
           <div class="zone" id="line1">
           </div>
           <div class="zone" id="line2">
           </div>
           <div class="zone" id="line3">
           </div>
           <div class="zone" id="line4">
           </div>
        <div id="contenitore-testo-annotato">
           <ul class="ul-testo-annotato">
              <li class="li-testo-annotato">
                 <span onMouseOver="showLine('line1')" onMouseOut="hideLine('line1')">   
                    <p class="p-testo-annotato">My text...</p>
                 </span>
              </li>
           </ul>
<ul class="ul-testo-annotato">
              <li class="li-testo-annotato">
                 <span onMouseOver="showLine('line2')" onMouseOut="hideLine('line2')">   
                    <p class="p-testo-annotato">My text...</p>
                 </span>
              </li>
           </ul>
<ul class="ul-testo-annotato">
              <li class="li-testo-annotato">
                 <span onMouseOver="showLine('line3')" onMouseOut="hideLine('line3')">   
                    <p class="p-testo-annotato">My text...</p>
                 </span>
              </li>
           </ul>
<ul class="ul-testo-annotato">
              <li class="li-testo-annotato">
                 <span onMouseOver="showLine('line4')" onMouseOut="hideLine('line4')">   
                    <p class="p-testo-annotato">My text...</p>
                 </span>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
<div id="contenitore-immagine">
        <img class="dimensioni" src="tavole/2.jpg">
           <div class="zone" id="line5">
           </div>
           <div class="zone" id="line6">
           </div>
           <div class="zone" id="line7">
           </div>
           <div class="zone" id="line8">
           </div>
<div id="contenitore-testo-annotato">
           <ul class="ul-testo-annotato">
              <li class="li-testo-annotato">
                 <span onMouseOver="showLine('line5')" onMouseOut="hideLine('line5')">   
                    <p class="p-testo-annotato">My text...</p>
                 </span>
              </li>
           </ul>
<ul class="ul-testo-annotato">
              <li class="li-testo-annotato">
                 <span onMouseOver="showLine('line6')" onMouseOut="hideLine('line6')">   
                    <p class="p-testo-annotato">My text...</p>
                 </span>
              </li>
           </ul>
<ul class="ul-testo-annotato">
              <li class="li-testo-annotato">
                 <span onMouseOver="showLine('line7')" onMouseOut="hideLine('line7')">   
                    <p class="p-testo-annotato">My text...</p>
                 </span>
              </li>
           </ul>
<ul class="ul-testo-annotato">
              <li class="li-testo-annotato">
                 <span onMouseOver="showLine('line8')" onMouseOut="hideLine('line8')">   
                    <p class="p-testo-annotato">My text...</p>
                 </span>
              </li>
           </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Because i have to generate html from xml/xsl files. But is not really a problem when i know what kind of javascript/html structure i have to generate.

Comment: Just as an aside: you should change `contenitore-immagine` to classes instead of `id` - `id`s have to be unique, so your current output HTML is not valid.

Comment: But as you can see from my xml file i have different xml:id for each surface element. Maybe i could use a class instead of use anid attribute.

Comment: For me is not a a problem to include the external js files via xslt. This is pretty easy to do. The problem is to generate the right html from my xml structure using the right javascript function for let work the web view correctly.

Comment: @JLRishe do you have any solution?..

Comment: `p` elements don't belong into `span` elements. If you want to set up an event handler like `onmouseover` you can do that on any element so there is certainly no need to use `span` elements to have event handlers. Put them on the `p` or the `li` elements.

Comment: @JLRishe Finally i have solved it and my code works perfectly! :) If you want i can post the complete solution from my xml, javascript and xsl files.